# I want to retrieve values from database without using listview and display in textview feilds

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am able to read and write into database but in listview now I want to retrieve data from database into string and display it in textview.

Below is my database code and to retrieve this database information in another activity.

```
package com.example.panel_monitoring.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.panel_monitoring.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // User Table Columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PHONENUMBER = "user_phonenumber";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PRODUCTCODE = "user_productcode";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_VLL1 = "user_vll1";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_VLL2 = "user_vll2";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_VLL3 = "user_vll3";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PF = "user_PF";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_FREQ = "user_FREQ";


    // create table sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_PRODUCTCODE + " TEXT" + ")";

    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        //Drop User Table if exist
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * This method is to create user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void addUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PHONENUMBER, user.getPhonenumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PRODUCTCODE, user.getProductcode());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to fetch all user and return the list of user records
     *
     * @return list
     */
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID,
                COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
                COLUMN_USER_NAME,
                COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD,
                COLUMN_USER_PHONENUMBER,
                COLUMN_USER_PRODUCTCODE
        };
        // sorting orders
        String sortOrder =
                COLUMN_USER_NAME + " ASC";
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // query the user table
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,    //columns to return
                null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
                null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,       //group the rows
                null,       //filter by row groups
                sortOrder); //The sort order


        // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID))));
                user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)));
                user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL)));
                user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)));
                user.setPhonenumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PHONENUMBER)));
                user.setProductcode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PRODUCTCODE)));
                // Adding user record to list
                userList.add(user);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // return user list
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * This method to update user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PHONENUMBER, user.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PRODUCTCODE, user.getProductcode());

        // updating row
        db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to delete user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // delete user record by id
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String email) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";

        // selection argument
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};

        // query user table with condition
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                      //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

        // query user table with conditions
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

i have few more tables to add

Please provide help as soon as possible

user Adapter activity

```
package com.example.panel_monitoring.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.panel_monitoring.R;
import com.example.panel_monitoring.model.User;

import java.util.List;

public class UsersRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersRecyclerAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

    private List<User> listUsers;

    public UsersRecyclerAdapter(List<User> listUsers) {
        this.listUsers = listUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // inflating recycler item view
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_recycler, parent, false);

        return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(listUsers.get(position).getName());
        holder.textViewEmail.setText(listUsers.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.textViewPassword.setText(listUsers.get(position).getPassword());
        holder.textPhoneNumber.setText( listUsers.get( position ).getPhonenumber() );
        holder.textProductCode.setText( listUsers.get( position ).getProductcode() );

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.v(UsersRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),""+listUsers.size());
        return listUsers.size();
    }


    /**
     * ViewHolder class
     */
    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public AppCompatTextView textViewName;
        public AppCompatTextView textViewEmail;
        public AppCompatTextView textViewPassword;
        public AppCompatTextView textPhoneNumber;
        public AppCompatTextView textProductCode;

        public UserViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById( R.id.textViewName);
            textViewEmail = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            textViewPassword = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPassword);
            textPhoneNumber = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone_number);
            textProductCode = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewProduct_Code);
        }
    }

}
```

user Activity

```
package com.example.panel_monitoring.activities;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.panel_monitoring.R;
import com.example.panel_monitoring.adapters.UsersRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.panel_monitoring.model.User;
import com.example.panel_monitoring.sql.DatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class userActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppCompatActivity activity = userActivity.this;
    private AppCompatTextView textViewName;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewUsers;
    private List<User> listUsers;
    private UsersRecyclerAdapter usersRecyclerAdapter;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.userlistactivity);
       // getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside user Activity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        initViews();
        initObjects();

    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize views
     */
    private void initViews() {
        textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        recyclerViewUsers = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUsers);
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize objects to be used
     */
    private void initObjects() {
        listUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        usersRecyclerAdapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(listUsers);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewUsers.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewUsers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);

        String emailFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL");
        textViewName.setText(emailFromIntent);

        getDataFromSQLite();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to fetch all user records from SQLite
     */
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private void getDataFromSQLite() {
        // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                listUsers.clear();
                listUsers.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllUser());

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting your exact question. But if you are just starting development of app, I would recommended to use upgraded version of SQLiteDatabase **Room** instead SQLite. [Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Comment: show how you display data in ListVIew

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your code, the following displays a list of users in the RecyclerView. Clicking on an Item will result in that User's email being displayed in the TextView textViewName.

Additionally, if an Item in the displayed list is long-clicked, it will delete the respective User from the database and refresh the RecyclerView according to the changed database.

Just the one Activity **MainActivity** has been used (as such the initial email is hard coded).

## The code

### User.java (CODE ADDED)

To simplify adding some test Users, the following code, a constructor that allows a User to be built with parameters and a default constructor, may not have existed :-

```
public User() {}

public User(String name, String email, String password, String phonenumber, String productcode) {
    this.id = -1;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    this.productcode = productcode;
}
```

### UserListRefreshed.java (NEW)

This is an interface that is implemented by MainActivity and called by the RecyclerView's adapter when an item is clicked (to update the TextView) and also when an item is long-clicked to refresh the List.

```
public interface UserListRefreshed {
     void userListRefreshed();
     void userRetrieved(User user);
}
```

### DatabaseHelper.java

All the **db.close()**'s have been removed, it's inefficient to keep on closing the database and there were issue with your original code with db closed.

A new method has been added to delete a user row by pass the id rather than the User as per (this also returns the number of rows deleted, so this could be checked for 0 in which case there would be no need to refresh the list (this checking hasn't been included)) :-

```
//<<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>>>
public int deleteUserById(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_USER,COLUMN_USER_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}
```

### UserRecyclerAdapter.java

The bulk of the changes are to the **onBindViewHolder** and are the addition of the click/long-click listeners.

```
public class UsersRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersRecyclerAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

    private List<User> listUsers;
    public UsersRecyclerAdapter(List<User> listUsers) {
        this.listUsers = listUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // inflating recycler item view
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_recycler, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(listUsers.get(position).getName());
        holder.textViewEmail.setText(listUsers.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.textViewPassword.setText(listUsers.get(position).getPassword());
        holder.textPhoneNumber.setText( listUsers.get( position ).getPhonenumber() );
        holder.textProductCode.setText( listUsers.get( position ).getProductcode() );
        /**
         * IS this what is wanted?? i.e. get the user that has been clicked?
         */
        ((View)holder.textViewName.getParent()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)v.getContext()).userRetrieved(listUsers.get(position));
            }
        });
        //<<<<<<<<<< ADDITIONAL
        ((View)holder.textViewName.getParent()).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                final int idToDelete = listUsers.get(position).getId(); //<<<<<<<<<< get the id of the user that was long-clicked
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        DatabaseHelper dbhlpr = new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext());
                        dbhlpr.deleteUserById(idToDelete);
                        ((MainActivity)v.getContext()).userListRefreshed();
                    }
                }).start();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.v(UsersRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),""+listUsers.size());
        return listUsers.size();
    }


    /**
     * ViewHolder class
     */
    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public AppCompatTextView textViewName;
        public AppCompatTextView textViewEmail;
        public AppCompatTextView textViewPassword;
        public AppCompatTextView textPhoneNumber;
        public AppCompatTextView textProductCode;

        public UserViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textViewName =  view.findViewById( R.id.textViewName);
            textViewEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            textViewPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPassword);
            textPhoneNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone_number);
            textProductCode = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewProduct_Code);
        }
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

This is the equivalent of your **userActivity**

Rather than Suppress the warning about the memory leak, an alternative safe method called **getUserList()** has been added.

Note that the RecyclerView is now managed by the **manageRecyclerView** method that takes a List. If the adapter is null then it and the RecyclerView are setup otherwise the List is refreshed with the new list passed to the method.

The Activity implements the UserListRefreshed interface and therefore requires that the the template methods are used so methods **userListRefreshed** and **userRetrieved** have been added.

To provide testing data method **addSomeDataIfNone** has been added. This adds two users if no users exist.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserListRefreshed {

    //private AppCompatActivity activity = MainActivity.this;
    private AppCompatTextView textViewName;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewUsers;
    private List<User> listUsers = new ArrayList<>(); // Always initially going to be empty  so define it here
    private UsersRecyclerAdapter usersRecyclerAdapter;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.userlistactivity);
        // getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside user Activity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< Instiate the Database helper
        initViews();
        initObjects();
        addSomeDataIfNone(); // Add some testing data FOR TESTING/DEMONSTRATION
        getUserList(); //<<<<<<<<<< get the data
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize views
     */
    private void initViews() {
        textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        recyclerViewUsers = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUsers);
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize objects to be used
     */
    private void initObjects() {
        /*
         <<<<<<<<<< SEE manageRecyclerView >>>>>>>>>>
        listUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        usersRecyclerAdapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(listUsers);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewUsers.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewUsers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        */
        manageRecyclerView(new ArrayList<User>()); //<<<<<<<<<<
        String emailFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL");
        emailFromIntent = "mtnobody@nobodymail.com"; //<<<<<<<<<< as only the one activity email initially hardcoded
        textViewName.setText(emailFromIntent);
        //getDataFromSQLite(); see OUCH
        //getUserList(); //<<<<<<<<< alternative with no OUCH
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< REDUNDANT Replaced by getUserList >>>>>>>>>>
    // No potential memory leak with getUserList
    /**
     * This method is to fetch all user records from SQLite
     */
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") //!!!!!!!!!! OUCH
    private void getDataFromSQLite() {
        final List<User> newUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                newUserList.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllUser());
                listUsers.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllUser());
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Manage the RecyclerView
     * i.e. either set it up or refresh the list
     */
    private void manageRecyclerView(List<User> thelist) {
        if (usersRecyclerAdapter == null) {
            usersRecyclerAdapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(listUsers);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager lom = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(lom);
            recyclerViewUsers.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerViewUsers.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);
        } else {
            listUsers.clear();
            listUsers.addAll(thelist);
        }
        usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Get the UserList off the UI thread and then refresh the RecyclerView on the UI thread
     */
    private void getUserList() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final List<User> ul = databaseHelper.getAllUser();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        manageRecyclerView(ul);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void userListRefreshed() {
        getUserList();
    }

    /**
     * The Interface method called from within the
     * @param user
     */
    @Override
    public void userRetrieved(User user) {
        textViewName.setText(user.getEmail());
    }

    private void addSomeDataIfNone() {
        if (databaseHelper.getAllUser().size() > 0 ) return;
        databaseHelper.addUser(new User("Fred","fred@fredmail.com","password","1234567890","00000000001"));
        databaseHelper.addUser(new User("Bbert","bert@bertmail.com","password","1234567890","00000000001"));

    }
}
```

## Testing/Results

#### First run :-

[image]

- Note the default email.

#### Clicking on Fred the email changes

[image]

- clicking anywhere in the row works (the listeners use `view.getParent()`)
- Likewise clicking on Bert and Bert's email is displayed.

#### Long-Clicking Bert :-

[image]

- Bert has been deleted and the display refreshed

#### Rerun App :-

[image]

- Bert is still deleted
- If Fred as well as Bert were deleted then due to the check done by the addSomeDataIfNone method they would be added again (but because you have AUTOINCREMENT coded they would have higher id's).

---

P.S. it's inefficient to use `AUTOINCREMENT`, `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` on it's own would work and without the overheads [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), which has the first line saying :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. **It is usually not needed.** *(emphasis added)*